# .htaccess folder to virtual-folder rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible with Apache's RewriteEngine to do the following, and how?

This is the environment:

**domain.com** has a **folder** that contains a **index.html** page, htaccess is set to strip files so **domain.com/folder/** opens **domain.com/folder/index.html**

Now what i need to achieve is display **domain.com/folder/** content (the index.html) as it comes from **domain.com/virtualfolder/** where **virtualfolder** does not exist and the url has to show as **domain.com/virtualfolder/**

I hope what i wrote it is understandable.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^virtual-folder/(.*)$ folder/$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the directory index (without a `/`). Any way to make `/virtual-folder` also redirect to `/folder` ?

Comment: @XCS add another `RewriteRule ^virtual-folder$ folder [QSA]`

Answer (score 1):

You need an alias:

```
Alias /virtualfolder /full_path_to/domain.com/folder
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Alias is the most convenient way, but it is required to put the alias in the httpd.conf. If you rent some web space, the provider will usually only allow you to edit the .htaccess file, and it´s no possible to put an alias in there. In that case, you need to work with mod_rewrite. Just have the same problem right now when typing it.

However, if you rent some web space and you got Plesk 11.5 or 12.0 installed, there´s usually an option "virtual directory" (if not deactivated)