# Apache rewrite - Virtual dir to php script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Following the accepted answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702680/htaccess-folder-to-virtual-folder-rewriting), I constructed a rewrite rule which is pretty straight forward, but doesn't seem to work as designed.

```
# /st doesn't exist, it's virtual
example.com/st/sometext
```

Rewrites to

```
# /app is a symlink to /app.php, and this link works if entered directly
example.com/app/st/sometext
```

And the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^st/(.*)$ app/st/$1 [L]
```

This rule is at the top of the rewrite block, after which there are other rules, but those rules shouldn't apply, due to the [L] constraint.

The rewrite log file has this:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /st/sometext
(1) pass through /st/sometext
```

It doesn't seem like the rewrite rule is matching the url. What am I missing?

Comment: Your explanation and your rule are doing the opposite. Your rule means `rewrite st/XXX to app/st/XXX` which is not what you said in the beginning of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved the issue by switching over to nginx (lol) and implementing this rewrite rule:

```
location /st {
    rewrite ^/st/(.*)$ /app.php/st/$1 last;
}
```

The switchover to nginx really had little to do with the rewrite rule and more to do with getting away from apache 2.2 (default upstream version for centos), however with nginx, rewrite rules are more straight forward than apache's (imo).